# How to compare two latex files in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I need to compare New.tex http://pastebin.com/PCafGYwG with Old.tex http://pastebin.com/jRU8rhhV and get an output if the same vulnerability exists in both documents in the same IP.

E.g.: both files have the IP address 10.1.2.3.

**New.tex**

```
 \subsection {Summary of security vulnerabilities found on the host with IP address 10.1.2.3}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.5in}|p{4in}|p{0.4in}|} \hline
\textit{\textbf{No}} &\textit{\textbf{Severity level}} & \textit{\textbf{Vulnerability name}} & \textit{\textbf{More}} \\ \hline
     1  & \cellcolor{Red}High& DNS Server Cache Snooping Remote Information Disclosure  & \href{http://www.rootsecure.net/content/downloads/pdf/dns\_cache\_snooping.pdf}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     2  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & SSL Certificate with Wrong Hostname  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=45411}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     3  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & SSL Self-Signed Certificate  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=57582}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     4  & \cellcolor{SkyBlue}Low & SSL RC4 Cipher Suites Supported  & \href{http://www.nessus.org/u?217a3666}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
.............
.....................
...
```

**Old.tex**

```
.............
.......
......................
 \subsection {Summary of security vulnerabilities found on the host with IP address 10.1.2.3}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.5in}|p{4in}|p{0.4in}|} \hline
\textit{\textbf{No}} &\textit{\textbf{Severity level}} & \textit{\textbf{Vulnerability name}} & \textit{\textbf{More}} \\ \hline
     1  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & DNS Server Cache Snooping Remote Information Disclosure  & \href{http://www.rootsecure.net/content/downloads/pdf/dns\_cache\_snooping.pdf}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     2  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & SSL Certificate Cannot Be Trusted  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=51192}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     3  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & SSL Certificate with Wrong Hostname  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=45411}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     4  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & SSL Self-Signed Certificate  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=57582}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
..............
.......
...........
```

In that case,

both have the vulnerability ="DNS Server Cache Snooping Remote Information Disclosure" "SSL Certificate with Wrong Hostname" "SSL Self-Signed Certificate"

I need to output

only the vulnerability summary as below

```
\subsection {Summary of security vulnerabilities found on the host with IP address 10.1.2.3}
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.2in}|p{0.5in}|p{4in}|p{0.4in}|} \hline
\textit{\textbf{No}} &\textit{\textbf{Severity level}} & \textit{\textbf{Vulnerability name}} & \textit{\textbf{More}} \\ \hline
     1  & \cellcolor{Red}Medium & DNS Server Cache Snooping Remote Information Disclosure  & \href{http://www.rootsecure.net/content/downloads/pdf/dns\_cache\_snooping.pdf}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     2  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & SSL Certificate with Wrong Hostname  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=45411}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
     3  & \cellcolor{BurntOrange}Medium & SSL Self-Signed Certificate  & \href{http://www.tenable.com/plugins/index.php?view=single&id=57582}{$\Rightarrow$}  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

How can I achieve this on linux using bash scripting, awk, sed or any other method?

Comment: I would start doing something like: `awk '/10.1.2.3/ {f=1} f; /\end{center}/ {f=0}' new > stuff_new` to store a specific block and then the same with `old` file. Then you can compare them somehow, although they look pretty different.

Comment: what's the filter rule? why you take medium between high and medium?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare two files using the `diff` command or the `diffuse` GUI tool:

```
diff Old.tex New.tex
```

or

```
diffuse Old.tex New.tex
```

For a more in-depth analysis, I would recommend writing a short python (or perl) script, where you read both files, find the lines you are interested in, compare them, and make the required substitutions.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would be to find unique text to search for in the first line, and then use `grep` to locate that line and add `-A8` to also capture the next 8 lines of context. In your case something like the following might do:

```
grep -A8 {Summary\ of\ security\ vulnerabilities filename
```

Presuming that combination of words is unique to the vulnerabilities line, then you would get the lines above that you indicate are desired.

Comment: This not really answers the question, how to get the same blocks from two latex files.

Comment: Let's see if I understand what your are saying? My answer showed how to get the summary he needed from `filename`. Are you saying he is not smart enough to substitute `filename=oldfilename` and then `filename=newfilename` to get 2 summary blocks to compare?

Comment: Simply, your answer doesn't give the wanted output, e.g. _get an output if the same vulnerability exists in both documents in the same IP._ You sending the poor guy on a **tour**. You didn't hate when the keys get that small? :)